# How to make Splash Screen in Android studio to actually load stuff

Tags: android, screen, loading, splash-screen

I've been looking at many many articles and youtube tutorials on how to make splash screen and non of them answered my question. Is splash screen actually loading and how to make one

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on how you implement splash screen. If this you are using the `core-splashscreen` library from Google, then you need to use **setKeepVisibleCondition**:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
        splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition{ isLoadingFinished }
```

You need to create a variable  isLoadingFinished that becomes true when the loading is finished. Place it in your ViewModel is a good practice.

If you use the old methods of creating a splash screen with a separate activity, just call the desired intent after the loading is complete...